# PHP regex that blocks special signs and spaces

Tags: php

I want it to block signs as !@#%^&*()_+ and allow no spaces.
ive tried

```
preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', $usernam)
```

Comment: why do you want to block special chars?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a personal regex development service.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $username)) {
  echo 'invalid username';
}
```

Edit: my bad, forgot the minimum of 1 (+ sign)

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` (hyphen is permitted). Also `/[a-z0-9-]/i`, and other shortcuts for alphanumerics.

Comment: He says 'signs as' which makes it unclear as to what exactly he does and doesn't want to allow. He could add \- to the regex (or simpy - if it's at the beginning or end of the class)